# MVC @Html.Display

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have something like:

```
     <input type="text" name="TerrMng" id="TerrMng"/>
```

in HTML. What is the equivalent of the above using @Html.Display?

I tried using:
        @Html.Display("TerrMng", TerrMng)

but was not successful. Note that I like to use @Html.Display but not sure how to translate the ID value so that it shows up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick for you. Adding the TerrMng as a 2nd parameter sets the value of the created html but the variable must come from your Model on load.

```
@Html.Display("TerrMng");
```